# Facing error while creating an array of object referances in java

Tags: java, arrays, reference

public class HashChaining
{……

```
 class HashTable
{
    int tsize; LLNode Table[];
};
public static void main(String []args)
{
    HashChaining eg;
    HashChaining.HashTable h;
    h=eg.new HashTable();
    h.Table=eg.new LLNode[11];
```

………..
     }
}

getting error while compiling:
HashChaining.java:85: error: '(' expected
        h.Table=eg.new LLNode[11];
                             ^
1 error

Comment: Can you please post your LLNode class too?

Comment: class LLNode
{
  int key;
  Student value=new Student ();
  LLNode next;
}
class Student
{
 String name;
String branch;
}

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I would do it and does not give any compilation error.

```
public class HashChaining {


    class HashTable {
        int tsize;
        LLNode Table[];
    }

    class LLNode {
        int key;
        Student value = new Student();
        LLNode next;
    }

    class Student {
        String name;
        String branch;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashChaining eg = new HashChaining();
        HashChaining.HashTable h = eg.new HashTable();
        h.Table = new LLNode[11];
    }
}
```